# how to create a PHP file on the server with dynamic input

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel and I created a multi-tenant app using the database connections, now I need to be able to create the contents of the database.php automatically with my chosen input.

Sample of database.php:

```
'connections' => [

    'db1' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => 'db1',
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ],

    'db2' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => 'db2',
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ]
]
```

So basically I will have a form that will ask those required fields like db name, connection name, password, etc.  My problem is that I dont have a fixed amount of connections, could be one, two, four, w/e and file_put_contents() requires a string not an array of data. So my question is how to create this database.php file with the input from my form, create the opening and closing bracket and everything needed?  Is there a function that will convert an Array to a String retaining the brackets and operators?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't do this. Please. Yes it's an efficient solution compared with reading parsing the structure from data but self modifying code is inherently **VERY** dangerous.

Comment: Hi, its possible to do it securely, this will be a private admin app that will create and monitor instances of another unrelated app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go down on that road, make sure you have a template file, and you can setup placeholders that you simple replace.

Your sample template file would hold all requirements + placeholders for each info you need.

```
    'db{index}' => [
             ...other key+values and it's placeholders...
        ],
```

And simply you can loop and concat as many times this block in your final `database.php` file.

---

on the other hand you could do this on the fly, some snippet to guide you.

```
$nameKey = 'NameOfConnection';

$dataSync = AtlasBases::find($id_client);

Config::set('database.connections.' . $nameKey, array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $dataSync->site_db_server,
        'database'  => $dataSync->site_db_base,
        'username'  => $dataSync->site_db_user,
        'password'  => $dataSync->site_db_password,
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
));
# And set the new connection to my models

$imobModel = new ImobImoveis;
$imobModel->setConnection($nameKey);
```

Comment: Sorry, on the fly doesnt work for my app due to the way that I implemented the code, the most straight forward way is to create the file which works fine but I dont want to keep creating it manually,  Could you provide an extended example of the template way and the loop, maybe provide a link?